# auto redirect to clean urls

Tags: php, clean-urls

how can i auto redirect a site from dirty url to clean url in php , something like

```
http://www.mysite.com?page=page1&action=action1
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/page1/action1
```

Comment: I'd recommend you give an error for links like that to ensure canonical usage. It also helps to prevent wannabe hackers from trying to break your site!

Comment: Is this *really* what you want? Is it not the other way round?

Comment: Thanks everybody. but all i wanted is to approach **clean url** mechanism in my webpage (for SEO ) [www.kcdipesh.com.np](http://www.kcdipesh.com.np/) And more important is that it  is a single entry page so there is no folders to redirect my pages to. could you guys suggest me what is the best idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to check if it was clean request or not. 
Otherwise you will fall into infinite loop

Here is an *example* from one of my projects:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^game/([0-9]+)/ /game.php?newid=$1
```

game.php

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $row = dbgetrow("SELECT * FROM games WHERE id = %s",$_GET['id']);
  if ($row) {
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
    Header( "Location: /game/".$row['id']."/".seo_title($row['name'])); 
  } else {
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 404 Not found" ); 
  }
  exit;
}

if (isset($_GET['newid'])) $_GET['id'] = $_GET['newid'];
```

So, you have to verify, if it was direct "dirty" call or rewritten one.
And then redirect only if former one.
You need some code to build clean url too.

And it is also very important to show 404 instead of redirect in case url is wrong.

Comment: Correct header responses are well worth a mention.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Apache you can use the mod_rewrite module and set the rules in a .htaccess file in your httpdocs folders or web root. I don't see any reason to invoke a PHP process to do redirection when lower level components will do the job far better.

[An example from Simon Carletti](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/page\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.site/page/%1.pdf [R=302,L]
```

Comment: i think he is asking for a php solution

Comment: @Fender I don't see any reason to invoke a PHP process to do redirection when lower level components will do the job far better.

Comment: thats right, i wouldn't do it with php either, but he mentioned it in his question. but your solution is good

Comment: I think it's not an answer at all. One can answer ANY question on SO this lame way

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Using your recommendation I have just posted this as an answer to as many SO questions as I can!

Comment: Unacceptable, no. However it wasn't particularly helpful I agree.

Comment: But even if a contribution gets fixed, far be it from @Col. Shrapnel to actually revert a downvote.

Comment: @Pekka I don't think anyone was asking for voting to change? I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Treffynnon my understanding was that the answer was downvoted because it was incorrect, and subsequently edited to make it more correct. I think it goes without saying that one removes one's downvote if there is no longer anything incorrect in the post. This has nothing to do with you, just picking a bone with that user. Never mind.

Comment: @Pekka I get the context now and see what you are driving at! :)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/".$_GET['page']."/".$_GET['action']);
```

you should check whether the values are set before trying to redirect