# How can achieve a clean URL redirect

Tags: php, forms, validation, redirect, meta

So I have a form which when submitted executes a php file containing the following redirect.

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$nexturl.'" />';
```

As most people will know this isn't a clean/proffesional way of redirecting.

Is it possible to include a file just containing a redirect using header location, however I will require the variable that is created in my process.php file.

For example create using a php include:

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/redirect.php'); ?>
```

Then within redirect.php

```
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

Comment: whats the question ?  Is a redirect (header) inside a include possible? : yes

Comment: @birdspider Sorry as usually I haven't phrased my question well, basically can I do a redirect(header) at the bottom of a php file as I need to generate the variable before passing it to the header location,

Comment: Maybe this so question can hel you http://stackoverflow.com/q/5595445/5476782

Answer (score 1):

yes you can redirect (that is: set/reset/unset any header you want) as long as no output happend before

(none, not even whitespace or BOM (utf-8 byte order mark) - iirc)

in case you have output you can capture it via `ob_start` and output if afterwards

oddly enough: this is even made quite clear in the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)